# Add or remove permisssion for Find Connection button

Tags: administration, permissions, user, salesforce2salesforce

How do I remove the *Find Connection* search layout button particular user? This button appears on the list view search layout and I would like to disable it on a per-user basis.

Comment: This question could do with some additional detail. Which search layout? Screenshot? Some context?

Comment: Contact object Search Layout. It is related the List view search layout.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Salesforce to Salesforce feature.

If you don't want it on, you can disable S2S completely by going to `Setup > Customize > Salesforce to Salesforce > Settings`

Otherwise, as you have probably discovered, you can remove the button from the search layout.

Finally, [according to the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_send_invitation.htm&language=en_US), only users whose profile (or a permission set) has the *Manage Connections* permission are able to perform this function. So you can disable it in the profile of any users *except the standard System Administrator* profile, standard profiles being read-only for most permissions.

Comment: Thanks Peter for given solution.

I tried above solution. But it is not working to me. I followed the below steps.
1. Go to  the S2S, Enable the Find connection.
2. In the search layout Enable the Find connection button in contact object.
3. In XYZ profile Enable the Manage Connections permission.

But that profile user not able to see the Find connection button in List view on Contact object 
Thanks!